# how to remove one url parameter and keep another?

Tags: php, parsing, url, hyperlink, uri

i have this youtube url

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N51Etoikfw&feature=youtube_gdata

i need to remove the feature parameter and leave the v video id

so the result would be

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N51Etoikfw

can you help me achieve this result please using php and or regex

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP parse_url, http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to parse all parts of the URL and then stitch it back together.